# How I can add an optional parameter in REST API URL

Tags: 8

How I can add an optional parameter in drupal 8 REST API URL

```
"canonical" = "/content/get/{id}"
```

But I have to add value for `id` here, How I can make this `id` optional

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and solved it by adding the current request from the request stack to my resource:

**RestBase.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\api\Plugin\rest;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

class RestBase extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;
  /**
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
   */
  protected $currentRequest;

  /**
   * 
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param type $pluginId
   * @param type $pluginDefinition
   * @param array $serializerFormats
   * @param \Drupal\api\Plugin\rest\resource\LoggerInterface $logger
   * @param \Drupal\api\Plugin\rest\resource\AccountProxyInterface $currentUser
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $pluginId, $pluginDefinition, array $serializerFormats, LoggerInterface $logger, AccountProxyInterface $currentUser, Request $currentRequest) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $pluginId, $pluginDefinition, $serializerFormats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
    $this->currentRequest = $currentRequest;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $pluginId, $pluginDefinition) {
    return new static(
        $configuration, 
        $pluginId, 
        $pluginDefinition, 
        $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'), 
        $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'), 
        $container->get('current_user'),
        $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
    );
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param array $message
   * @param integer $cache
   * @return ResourceResponse
   */
  protected function getResponse($message, $cache = 0) {
    $build = [
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => $cache,
      ]
    ];

    $response = new ResourceResponse($message);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($build);

    return $response;
  }

}
```

**TestResource.php (the actual REST resouce)**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\api\Plugin\rest\RestBase;

/**
 * Test resource.
 * 
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "test_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Test API Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/test-resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TestResource extends RestBase {

  /**
   * 
   * @return ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    if (!$this->currentUser->hasPermission('use ' . $this->pluginId . ' service')) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Access denied.');
    }

    $id = $this->currentRequest->get('id');

    $message = [
      'message' => 'Hello, you called service: ' . $this->pluginId,
      'id' => $id,
    ];

    return parent::getResponse($message);
  }

}
```

In my own base class `RestBase` I added the current request from the request stack (besides the `AccountProxy` for permission purposes) by overriding the `create` method of the `ResourceBase` class. You can then access query parameters in your REST resource by calling the `get($key)` method on the request object.

You will need to pass your parameters in the API URI like so: `http://localhost/api/test-resource?_format=<your-format>&<parameter1>=<value1>`. Considering this example API URI you would access `parameter1` via `$value1 = $this->currentRequest->get('parameter1')`.

I guess that it is not possible to have slugs in your resources at the moment. If someone knows how please do tell :).

Comment: This works great. RestBase is optional though. You can just add the $currentRequest bits to your `class MyResource extends ResourceBase`.

Answer (score 3):

For a custom REST resource supporting only GET where an optional path param could be for filtering, you can add a default for a parameter in the routes() method and thus make it optional.

For example this has the essential bits:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource for groups that may have inventory.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "owning_groups",
 *   label = @Translation("All Groups That May Own Inventory (optionally limited to one space)"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/rest/owning_groups/{nid}",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class OwningGroupsRestResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to a GET request.
   *
   * @param int $nid
   *   Space node ID.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   *   Rest Response with all group nid/titles.
   *
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public function get($nid): ResourceResponse {
    $space_node = NULL;
    if ($nid) {
      /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $space_node */
      $space_node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
      if (!$space_node || $space_node->bundle() !== 'space') {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('No such space');
      }
    }
...

   return $response;
 }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function routes() {
    $collection = parent::routes();
    // Add defaults for optional parameters.
    $defaults = [
      'nid' => 0,
    ];
    foreach ($collection->all() as $route) {
      $route->addDefaults($defaults);
    }
    return $collection;
  }

}
```

see also:
[How I can add an optional parameter in REST API URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213184/how-i-can-add-an-optional-parameter-in-rest-api-url)

Answer (score 1):

In your your_module.routing.yml file in your route configuration

```
defaults:
  id: 'default-id'
```

see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310425) under Optional parameters for more information

If you are trying to alter existing route you should use [RouteSubscriber](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643)

Or if you need to display something else on `/content/get/` you should create additional route without `{id}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using it as a REST plugin. I define the path using "@RestResource" annotation. I will try RouteSubscriber

Comment: hi @Unnikrishnan are you found solution?

Comment: @vijay - not yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions on this page that explain how to do it. A different question is whether you should do it :)

From [Drupal.org issue RestResource plugins: use get() method with optional parameter (or no parameter) to signal list support?](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2908800):

One concept about the differences of collections and items:

> A "collection resource" is likely to support POST and GET. An "individual item resource" will probably support GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE.

Another thought on general domain:

> At least I think optional parameters are a flaw. I think on the REST domain level there is no notion of optional parameters. There is a collection resource and there is an individual object resource.

And about using Views:

> The REST module basically has spent no time/thought on how to deal with collections. AFAICT it deferred that entirely to Views.

**In summary:** it seems the standard idea is that you can use Views for collections or you can write 2 Resources - one for the collection and one for the item.